# SSRS Charts in new row

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have total 20 Charts. When i display them in report it is showing 20 reports Horizontally.
I want to display them 5 in a row. How to achieve this using SSRS grouping.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why doesn't your current solution work? How are you grouping the charts? What does your over-arching dataset look like?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/65/posts/11568/better-way-of-repeating-charts-based-on-parameters.aspx) in the past.

It's a blog post named `"Better way of repeating charts based on parameters"`